# Why would a Pokemons CP show as "???"?

Tags: pokemon-go

Normally when I encounter a Pokemon, it displays the CP. A Venomoth popped up and I engaged to catch it. This time the CP was shown as "???".

I eventually caught it and it's CP was 285. Was there any signifcance to why the CP was initially hidden?

[image: a Venomoth with unknown CP]

Comment: This happened to me with a Weepinbell, although his CP ended up as 156. I'm curious as well.

Comment: I think time will tell, but I think it has to do with your trainer level or whether you've aired got pokedex info on it or not

Comment: It normally does this to me when I watch one to find it, or it is a higher cp Pokémon

Comment: What is CP? I have just started playing the game and it never told me what it is.

Comment: @Diti Abbreviation of Combat Power

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The CP is hidden if it's higher than any Pokémon's CP that you have ever had in your possession. This is easily seen when starting out a new game, where all of the starter choices' CPs are hidden, despite being very low.

Comment: Does this include only explicitly caught CP? If I level my top pokemon up from 500 to 1000, will I see a wild pokemon at level 750, or at "**???**"?

Comment: @StephenSchrauger From my experiences, it will be ???, though more testing is needed to be certain.

Comment: @Mego On the same note what if I we're to hatch or evolve my highest CP pokemon. Would that still be the highest "caught"?

Comment: @DasBeasto As far as I can tell, by going through my in-game journal, the CP of a Pokémon you're trying to catch displays as "???" if it has a higher CP than any other Pokémon that you've *caught* - hatching, evolving, and powering up don't play a role here.

Comment: I'm sure that there's a threshold. I only saw 1 pokemon with hidden CP. And it was a Ponyta with 430CP, when I was at level 7. I've seen and found a few 900+ CP pokemons, and they all showed the CP. Or the CP of your pokemons has influence in the CP being hidden?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Actually, I managed to confirm that just earlier today - I found a wild Pinsir whose CP was just below my highest CP (an Exeggutor that I evolved and manually powered up). I had forgotten about updating this until I saw your comment, so thanks!